# Does TestNG support WARN type errors beyond just PASS/FAIL?

Tags: testng

I am using TestNG in conjunction with Selenium to test a web application, which has multi-page flows (e.g. sign up, and complete your profile across 8 different pages).

I've used Selenium's PageObject's approach and implemented checking code in every page that checks for e.g.  "php error" messages are not shown in the page, in this case if a single page detects this error the complete flow  (which is a @Test method referencing multiple PageObjects internally) will fail.

There are some errors that I'd like to report but not mark the whole flow as failed (e.g. incorrectly escaping quotes or HTML characters).  I may have a common error in all pages which does not preclude the whole flow from executing and it would save time if I can report the warning and still be able to continue testing.

Is [Reporter](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Reporter.html) the best way to do this?  From a usability perspective it would be nice to show reports with RED (fail), GREEN (pass) and ORANGE (warn) colors.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if this is easily done too, or if there's something that can be done out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to do this, though it's a bit of a hack. In the test method where you want to warn instead of pass fail, do this:

```
...
import org.testng.Reporter;
...

@Test
public void myTestMethod(){
   if( someConditionThatCausesWarning ) {
       Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setAttribute("warn", "My warning message");
   }
}
```

This sets an attribute on the test result object, which you can then access in your custom listener and reporter. I set the verbosity to 0:

```
...
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setVerbose(0);
...
```

which turns off the default real-time reporting.

Then in the listener and/or reporter you do:

```
testResult.getAttribute("warn");
```

to see if there's a warning instead of a PASS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to modify the reporter except by going into the source and making the changes yourself (and I'm open to making the code easier to modify if you're tempted to go down that route, e.g. making it easy to subclass, etc...) or by writing your own reporter (I understand why you'd want to avoid that).

Have you considered using Reporter.log()? These strings will appear in the final reports in a special section.

Also, note that TestNG is getting new reports in the new version:

http://beust.com/weblog/2012/01/01/ushering-testng-into-the-new-year/

Comment: I'd be interested in this very much. Reporter.log() is OK, but the result just lists passes and fails, with no warnings. I'd like n passes, n fails, n warnings. And I'd like to do any kind of arbitrary warning levels, "moderate", "severe" etc.