# In TestNG is there a way to mark a test with WARNING status instead of just pass and fail?

Tags: java, testing, testng

In TestNG we have tests to be marked as passed or failed.Is it possible to mark it as warning or some other state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135558/does-testng-support-warn-type-errors-beyond-just-pass-fail

Comment: Thanks.Did not get it on searching!